Webgl2's deleteTexture doesn't seem to be able to access the GPU memory usage?
When I run a webgl2 program in the latest chrome, I use deleteTexture to delete a texture of several hundred MB, but I find that the gpu memory is not reclaimed after executing deleteTexture. Why and how to solve it?
When I use the following method, the memory usage can be released immediately. Unfortunately, I cannot do this in production.
const ext = gl.getExtension('WEBGL_lose_context')!;
ext.loseContext();


how exactly are you determining GPU memory usage?

Chrome's Task Manager
